# scrapy.Request does not callback my function

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm sorry if my question is too trivial but I'm behind a wall since this morning... I'm new in scrapy and I already read the doc but I haven't found my answer...

I  wrote this spider and when I call `parse_body` in `rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_body'),)`, it does :

```
tchatch = response.xpath('//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]/div/a/@href').extract()
            print('\n TROUVE \n')
            print(tchatch)
            print('\n DONE \n')
```

But when I rename, everywhere in my code, the function `parse_body` by just `parse`, it just does :

```
    print('\n EN FAIT, ICI : ', response.url, '\n')
```

It seems that my `scrapy.Request` requests are never called....
I even print a lot of useless things to know if my code was running the functions but it prints nothing except the `print` wrote above.

Any idea please?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
import numbers
from fnac.items import FnacItem
from urllib.request import urlopen
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Fnac(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'FnacCom'
    allowed_domains = ['fnac.com']
    start_urls = ['http://musique.fnac.com/a10484807/The-Cranberries-Something-else-CD-album']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_body'),
    )

    def parse_body(self, response):
        item = FnacItem()

        nb_sales = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/span/text()').re(r'([\d]*) ventes')
        country = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').re(r'([A-Z].*)')

        item['nb_sales'] = ''.join(nb_sales).strip()
        item['country'] = ''.join(country).strip()

        print(response.url)
        test_list = response.xpath('//a/@href')
        for test_list in response.xpath('.//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]'):
            tchatch = response.xpath('//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]/div/a/@href').extract()
            print('\n TROUVE \n')
            print(tchatch)
            print('\n DONE \n')

        yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_iframe, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_iframe(self, response):
        f_item1 = response.meta['item']

        print('\n EN FAIT, ICI : ', response.url, '\n')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(response.url), "lxml")
        iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
        if (len(iframexx) != 0):
            for iframe in iframexx:
                yield scrapy.Request(iframe.attrs['src'], callback=self.extract_or_loop, meta={'item': f_item1})
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.extract_or_loop, meta={'item': f_item1})

    def extract_or_loop(self, response):
        f_item2 = response.meta['item']

        print('\n PEUT ETRE ICI ? \n')
        address = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Adresse \: (.*)\n?.*')
        email = response.xpath('//body//div/ul/li[contains(text(),"@")]/text()').extract()
        name = response.xpath('//body//div/p[@class="customer-policy-label"]/text()').re(r'Infos sur la boutique \: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*)')
        phone = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Tél \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        siret = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Siret \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        vat = response.xpath('//body//div/text()').re(r'.*TVA \: (.*)')

        if (len(name) != 0):
            print('\n', name, '\n')
            f_item2['name'] = ''.join(name).strip()
            f_item2['address'] = ''.join(address).strip()
            f_item2['phone'] = ''.join(phone).strip()
            f_item2['email'] = ''.join(email).strip()
            f_item2['vat'] = ''.join(vat).strip()
            f_item2['siret'] = ''.join(siret).strip()
            yield f_item2
        else:
            for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
                list_urls = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
                list_iframe = response.xpath('//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]/div/a/@href').extract()
                if (len(list_iframe) != 0):
                    for list_iframe in list_urls:
                        print('\n', list_iframe, '\n')
                        print('\n GROS TCHATCH \n')
                        yield scrapy.Request(list_iframe, callback=self.parse_body)
                for url in list_urls:
                    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_body)
```

Comment: Why not using `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider` if you are not even using real Rules?

Comment: Because if I put `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`, I have this error `raise NotImplementedError`

Comment: That's maybe because you don't implement *parse* method as is.

Comment: How could I do that? I don't know a lot of things in scrapy and python... Do I have to change `parse_body` to `parse`? Or to write another function called `parse`?

Comment: Read the description: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider

Comment: Any answer for this? I got the same issue

Answer (score 2):

In the scrapy documentation for the CrawlSpider, there is a warning:

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

You can check this out, here is the [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)

Comment: Thanks, I will check the link... And do you have any idea on the other problem please? If I wrote parse_body, my requests don't work neither...

Comment: @P.Postrique I have tried to debug your code first thing I did is change the `parse_body` to `parse_start_url`, this allowed the second function `parse_iframe` to be called but in this function there are links that you are accessing that are being redirected like this one:
    2017-07-13 12:31:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://secure.fnac.com/Account/Logon/Logon.aspx?LogonType=Standard&PageAuth=X&pagepar=&PageRedir=https%3a%2f%2fsecure.fnac.com%2faccount%2falerting> from <GET https://secure.fnac.com/account/alerting> which is the login page

Comment: Isn't it strange that just by changing the name, my function is called? I don't understand...
And is it normal that `parse_iframe` is just called once?

Comment: No it's not, as I said earlier, always aim to use methods in the Scrapy class you want to inherit from. But point here is the redirect to the login page, seems like a certain url is protected