# scrapy.Request does not execute callback function to process custom URL

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I would expect to see "HIT" in my Visual Studio console but the `process_listing` function is never executed.
When I run `scrapy crawl foo -O foo.json` I get error:

> start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests()) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075386/scrapy-request-does-not-callback-my-function).

```
import json
import re
import os
import requests
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import html2text

class FooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/item.json?lang=en']

    def start_requests(self):
        r = requests.get(self.start_urls[0])
        cont = r.json()
        self.parse(cont)

    def parse(self, response):
        for o in response['objects']:
            if o.get('option') == "buy" and o.get('is_available'):   
                listing_url = "https://www.example.com/" + \
                     o.get('brand').lower().replace(' ','-') + "-" + \
                     o.get('model').lower() + "-"
                if o.get('make') is not None:
                    listing_url += o.get('make') + "-"
                listing_url += o.get('year').lower() 
                print(listing_url) #a valid url is printed here

                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url=response.urljoin(listing_url), 
                    callback=self.process_listing
                )

    
    def process_listing(self, response):
        #this function is never executed
        print('HIT')
        yield item
```

I tried:

- `url=response.urljoin(listing_url)`
- `url=listing_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`sractpy.Spider.start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.Spider.start_requests), we see:

> **This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl for this spider.** It is called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for scraping. Scrapy calls it only once, so it is safe to implement start_requests() as a generator.

(emphasis mine)

Your `start_requests` method doesn't return anything (aka it returns `None`):

```
    def start_requests(self):
        r = requests.get(self.start_urls[0])
        cont = r.json()
        self.parse(cont)
```

So when scrapy calls `iter(self.spider.start_requests()`, it ends up asking for `iter(None)`, and `None` isn't iterable.

Comment: Thanks I added `        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.start_urls[0], 
            callback=self.parse
        )` to `start_requests` and that fixed it